# What's the easiest/best way to be informed of a Director selling shares of a company on London's AIM market?

Tags: stocks, investing, united-kingdom

I was wondering whether anyone had anything set up whereby it would 'push' information about Director's dealings on any particular company, in this case a company on London AIM market.

Is there a website/tool that I can use to build some sort of feed for this kind of info? I don't want to have to check periodically at each individual company's notes in my stocks/shares platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the best info with least fuss:

http://www.directorsholdings.com/

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [LSE](http://www.londonstockexchange.com/home/homepage.htm) website and go to the company's stock page. In this example I have taken  [NationalGrid](http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/prices-and-markets/stocks/summary/company-summary.html?fourWayKey=GB00B08SNH34GBGBXSET1) . Go the **Latest News** and click **More**. There you can see all regulatory filings for transactions done by the directors. I believe companies are legally asked to feed in information to the stock exchanges, where they are listed, for full disclosure.

Else you can go and check on the [FT website](http://www.ft.com/home/uk) also.